# Page not rendering after adding if statement and use Selector hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Page not rendering after adding if statement and useSelector hook.

Here is my App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar"
import Feed from "./Feed"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectUser } from "./features/userSlice";
import Login from "./Login";

import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';

function App() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Header />

      {!user 
        ? ( <Login /> ) 
        : (
          <div className="app_body">
            <Sidebar />
            <Feed />
          </div>
        )
      }
     
      {/* Gidgets */} 

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The app component quits rendering after I place the app_body inside this if statement and adding both of these :

```
const user = useSelector(selectUser);
```

```
{!user 
  ? ( <Login />) 
  : (
    <div className="app_body">
      <Sidebar />
      <Feed />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my userSlice component if this is relevant:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  status: 'idle',
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  user:null,
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

export const {login, logout} = userSlice.actions;

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

I tried eliminating different pieces of code and it appears the two pieces of code mentioned caused it to stop rendering.

Comment: not sure this is the fix, but why do you have `user: null,` under the `initialState` argument in the `userSlice`? Shouldn't whatever you're trying to do with that be handled by the value of `initialState`?

Comment: After reviewing some other code I worked on, I think there's too much missing here, either that you left out of the question or your codebase. Take a look at this code https://github.com/bcstryker/portfolio-site/tree/main/store and you will see that I've included `listenerMiddleware` and `user.helper.ts` and finally the index file calls `configureStore` and `useDispatch`. Peruse this codebase, maybe it will help.

Comment: Hey guys, I just looked in my store component:import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});   ......and I had count:userReducer instead of user: userReducer...that was the issue. Thak you guys so much for the help!

Comment: it's just me here but glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I just looked in my `store component`:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'; 
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice'; 

export const store = configureStore({ reducer: { user: userReducer, }, });
```

And I had

`count:userReducer` instead of `user: userReducer`
That was the issue.

Thank you guys so much for the help!

Comment: I see that you are new here so in case you didn't know, now that you have answered your own question you can click the checkmark next to your own answer to mark this question as answered. You might have to wait 24 hours, not sure.